# Set timing for 90 days javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to hide a div for 24 hours once user closes it. the below code works fine for it. But how do I set it for 90 days instead of 24 hours with the same script?

I tried adding `h*90*24*60*60*1000` but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

```
 //Get current time
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  //Add hours function
  Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {    
     this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000)); 
     return this;   
  }
  //Get time after 24 hours
  var after24 = new Date().addHours(10).getTime();
  //Hide div click
  $('.cookie_panel > span').click(function(){
      //Hide div
      $(".divclass").fadeOut();
      //Set desired time till you want to hide that div
      localStorage.setItem('desiredTime', after24); 
  });
  //If desired time >= currentTime, based on that HIDE / SHOW
  if(localStorage.getItem('desiredTime') >= currentTime)
  {
      $('.divclass').hide();
  }
  else
  {
      $('.divclass').show();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried adding `h*90*24*60*60*1000` but it didn't work.

That's because `h` there is meant to represent *hours* (which is why the method is called `addHours`). The code using it is passing in `10` (not `24`), so you're getting a date **900** days in the future, not **90**.

Remove the `h*` from that and it will give you 90 days. I'd also change the name of the method and not pass anything into it if you're using a fixed amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a little mistake, just remove the multiplication of h : (h*) from the formula.
It should give you the correct value of 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have the same effect by setting the proper date:

```
var after90= new Date();
after90.setDate(after90.getDate()+90);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this. I am sharing the full function.

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
//Add hours function
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {    
 this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000)); 
 return this;   
}
Date.prototype.addDays = function(d) {    
 this.setDate(this.getDate() + d); 
 return this;   
}
//Get time after 90 days
var afte90days = new Date().addDays(90).getTime();

var curr_date = new Date(currentTime);
var afte90days_date = new Date(afte90days);
```